# SQL to find new vs repeat customers that ordered particular product in a given month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT
DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate) AS Month,
c.EmailAddress,
od.productcode AS SKU,
SUM(od.Quantity) as Quantity,
SUM((od.ProductPrice) * (od.Quantity) ) AS REVENUE,
(select count(o.OrderID) FROM Orders o WHERE c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN  '1/1/2010 00:00' AND getdate()) AS NO_OF_ORDERS,
(CASE WHEN exists (Select * from Orders 
       where CustomerID = c.CustomerId
          and orderDate < o.orderDate) 
       then 'Repeat' else 'New' end ) AS Customers
FROM Customers c
    join (Orders o join OrderDetails od
            on od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
        on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
WHERE
o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '01/31/17 23:59'
        AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
        AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
        AND od.ProductCode = 'CBTN850'
        AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0
GROUP BY DATEPART(mm,o.OrderDate),c.EmailAddress, od.productcode,c.CustomerID,o.OrderDate
```

working on this right now

```
 select Customers.EmailAddress,
    case when( c1.EmailAddress=Customers.EmailAddress then new  end) as customers
    from
    (SELECT
    EmailAddress,
    MIN(Orders.OrderDate) as FirstOrderdate
    FROM
    Customers
    INNER JOIN
    Orders
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderDetails
    ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
    WHERE Orders.OrderDate > '01/01/2017 00:00:00' 
     AND Orders.OrderDate <  '01/31/2017 00:00:00'
     AND Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
            AND OrderDetails.ProductPrice <> 0
            AND OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'CBTN850'
            AND OrderDetails.Quantity NOT LIKE 0
          AND Customers.EmailAddress NOT IN (
              SELECT Customers.EmailAddress FROM Customers
               INNER JOIN
               Orders
               ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
        WHERE Orders.OrderDate< '01/01/2017 00:00:00')c1 AS c1.EmailAddress=Customers.EmailAddress
    GROUP BY  Customers.EmailAddress
```

Trying to do a SQL query which shows new vs returning customer for a given month. New customer is that who has never ordered before.

```
    SELECT
        c.EmailAddress,
        od.productcode AS SKU,
        COUNT(o.OrderID) AS number_of_Orders,
        DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate) AS Month
    FROM
        Customers c
        JOIN Orders o
            ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
        JOIN OrderDetails od
            ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    WHERE
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '04/30/17 23:59'
            AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
            AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
            AND od.ProductCode = 'ABC01'
            AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(mm,o.OrderDate),
        c.EmailAddress,
        od.productcode
```

I wrote this code. But this is not how I want it to work. I want to see 
product code, New  customers and Repeat Customers as output. Can we do it by making two cases for new and repeat customer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with two CASES.

This is psuedocode:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN {Customer has other orders} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReturningCustomers,
SUM(CASE WHEN {Customer has no other orders} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewCustomers
```

Comment: can you please help me using this pseudo code with my code??

Comment: Yes, if you make an attempt, post it, and any error or incorrect results you get, and I will help debug it.

Comment: Column 'Orders.CustomerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. This is error i am getting..code i am using..

Comment: Add `Orders.CustomerID` to your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ..I did that..it is running but not differentiating between new and repeat customers

Comment: I would need to see your entire code to help debug it.   Can you add it to your question at the top of the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152561/discussion-between-c-174-and-tab-alleman).

Comment: You haven't attempted to employ my solution at all.   Where is the SUM() function?   You should take the pseudo code from my answer, and just replace the part in {curly braces} with real code.   HINT:  there is a perfect hint in Charles' answer above that shows how to detect whether a customer is new or returning.

Comment: please check the latest code i did...it is showing me duplicate emails and by putting sum in front of case it shows error

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate) Month,
   c.EmailAddress, od.productcode SKU,
   case when exists 
      (Select * from Orders 
       where CustomerID = c.CustomerId
          and orderDate < o.orderDate) 
       then 'Repeat' else 'New' end NewCustomer,
   COUNT(o.OrderID) Orders

FROM Customers c
    join (Orders o join OrderDetails od
            on od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
        on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 

WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '04/30/17 23:59'
    AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
    AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
    AND od.ProductCode = 'ABC01'
    AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0

GROUP BY DATEPART(mm,o.OrderDate), c.EmailAddress, od.productcode
```

if this causes a group by error, then add the subquery expression to the group by clause:

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate) Month,
   c.EmailAddress, od.productcode SKU,
   case when exists 
      (Select * from Orders 
       where CustomerID = c.CustomerId
          and orderDate < o.orderDate) 
       then 'Repeat' else 'New' end NewCustomer
   COUNT(o.OrderID) Orders,

FROM Customers c
    join (Orders o join OrderDetails od
            on od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
        on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 

WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '04/30/17 23:59'
    AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
    AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
    AND od.ProductCode = 'ABC01'
    AND od.Quantity NOT LIKE 0

GROUP BY DATEPART(mm,o.OrderDate), c.EmailAddress, od.productcode,
     case when exists 
      (Select * from Orders 
       where CustomerID = c.CustomerId
          and orderDate < o.orderDate) 
       then 'Repeat' else 'New' end
```

Comment: This will return an error, because the NewCustomer column is not an aggregate, nor is it in the GROUP BY.

Comment: @TabAlleman..yes it is giving error..what to do to overcome it?

Comment: @Tab, did you try it? It might not, as the column that this subquery is dependent on (`OrderDate`) IS in the group by. I have not tested it, but I added another SQL statement in case it does cause that issue.

Comment: @TabAlleman@Charles Bretana.. It is still giving me error with using a subquery in group by expression..Error reads:Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause...please help debug me

Comment: ahhh, the group by is not dependent on orderDate, it is dependent on the orderDate Month. the subquery is dependent on orderdate Itself. I will need to make them the same.

Comment: @Charles Bretana ..no it is not working either way..The query is running but not able to differentaite between new vs old customers

Answer (score 0):

Try the below (hope it helps or give you an idea)

to get the ProductCode with every customer Id  and the status

```
with ordersData as
(select o.customerId,od.ProductCode,count(distinct o.orderId)ordersCount from  Orders o         
        inner join OrderDetails od
            ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    WHERE
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '04/30/17 23:59'
            AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
            AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
            AND od.ProductCode = 'ABC01'
            AND od.Quantity <> 0
  group by o.customerId,od.ProductCode
)

,RepeatedCustomersT as
(select customerId,ProductCode,'Repeat' as CustomerStatus from ordersData where ordersCount>1)

,NewCustomersT as
(select customerId,ProductCode , 'New' as CustomerStatus from ordersData where ordersCount=1)

select  ProductCode ,customerId,CustomerStatus as RepeatedCustomersT
union all
select  ProductCode ,customerId,CustomerStatus as NewCustomersT
```

but if you want to get the output Like (Productcode - RepeatedCustomer- NewCustomers) you can try the below query

```
with ordersData as
(select o.customerId,od.ProductCode,count(distinct o.orderId)ordersCount from  Orders o         
        inner join OrderDetails od
            ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    WHERE
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '04/30/17 23:59'
            AND o.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
            AND od.ProductPrice <> 0
            AND od.ProductCode = 'ABC01'
            AND od.Quantity <> 0
  group by o.customerId,od.ProductCode
),
RepeatedCustomersT as
(
select customerId,ProductCode,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ProductCode order by customerId) rn  from ordersData where ordersCount>1
)
,NewCustomersT as
(
select customerId,ProductCode,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ProductCode order by customerId) rn from ordersData where ordersCount=1
)
select  ProductCode ,r.customerId as RepeatedCustomers, n.CustomerId as NewCustomers
from RepeatedCustomersT r full outer join NewCustomersT n on r.ProductCode=n.ProductCode and r.rn=n.rn
```